# Error on wiki page - Is it ok?

Tags: terminology

Taken from [Wikipedia on Windows and Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Windows_and_Linux)

> However such an approach has indeed produced several vulnerabilities,
>   although this is a rare case

Is that statement logically correct because it seems to contradict itself or am I just reading it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, considering the context:

> Anyone with programming experience is free to fix bugs and submit them for inclusion in future releases and updates. However such an approach has indeed produced several vulnerabilities, **although this is a rare case.**

It could have been misunderstood to mean that "allowing anyone with programming experience to fix bugs" as a rare case, whereas in actuality, the sentence means "the vulnerabilities are rare cases, they do not happen often."

Yes, this sentence is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

You're absolutely correct that the sentence could be better written, and other answers have given good suggestions.

If you're looking for a logical contradiction between *several* and *rare*, though, there is none. *Several* refers to the number of things (more than a few) whereas *rare* refers to a proportion of some population. If the population is large enough, than you can have rare things of which there are several: for example, *several NBA players have been under six feet, but they are rare*. In a very large population, rare cases can have even many instances: many people have eyes of different colours, but they are rare too!

Answer (score 2):

I think that sentence sounds confusing because it shifts from plural (several vulnerabilities) to singular (case).

A better way to phrase it would be

> However, in several rare cases, such an approach has produced vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it makes no sense as written.

Better expressed:

> However, such an approach has indeed produced several vulnerabilities, although these are  rare.